# How to save checkbox values to a multiselect picklist?

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my visualforce page I have a field 'Fruits', which has 4 checkboxes 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes', and 'Kiwi' as options under it. I can select multiple options. Now in my controller I want to save the selected values to a multiselect picklist 'Fruit__c' in the 'Tree__c' object. How can I do it?

Comment: These 4 checkboxes, are they HTML checkboxes or apex:inputCheckbox?

Comment: @Bachovski apex:inputCheckbox

Comment: possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/displaying-multiselect-picklist-as-checkboxes

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I saw that, but it doesn't solve my issues of saving the values to a multi select picklist.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have 4 boolean varialbes for each of the checkboxes in order to determine which one is selected:

```
public boolean apple {get; set;}
public boolean orange {get; set;}
public boolean grapes {get; set;}
public boolean kiwi {get; set;}
```

In your save method you can check which of the 4 is selected and build a semi-colon separated string with the values (it's how multi-select picklists store the values):

```
public void save()
{
    String selectedFruits = '';
    selectedFruits += apple == true ? 'Apple;' : '';
    selectedFruits += orange == true ? 'Orange;' : '';
    selectedFruits += grapes == true ? 'Grapes;' : '';
    selectedFruits += kiwi == true ? 'Kiwi;' : '';

    Tree__c treeRecord = new Tree__c();
    treeRecord.Fruit__c = selectedFruits;
    // set other fields
    insert treeRecord;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bachovski! Good point to know, that multilist picklists are stored as semi-colon separated values. Now what if I have 15 options instead of 4?

Comment: Same thing just keep appending to the string, having every selected value followed by a semi colon. Alternatively you can just expose that multipicklist field on the page and don't worry about all this. If you have limitations around that then have a look at this multi select component - https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist

Comment: Got it, thanks! :) But in my real case, I have 4 such fields with 15 options each! I feel there should be an effective way to do this??

Comment: Also I think the whole scenario will give you a better understanding. So there is one more object called Earth__c, where these 4 fields with their options are defined. I created those 4 fields in Fruit__c. Now In my controller, I am getting the options for the fields in Fruit__c from the fields in Earth__c, and displaying them on the visualforce page. I want the selected values on the visualforce page to be saved in the fields on Fruit__c. Please let me know if you have more questions on this.

Comment: @Knowme so does that mean that Earth__c and Fruit__c both fields have the same values?